# How do I find out which users are currently using an ms access database

Tags: database, vba, ms-access-2010

I'd like to know if there is a way of finding out the user names of the people sharing a database with me.

I know that I can use the environ("UserName") call to get my own username but I'd like to know who else is in the database.

Answer (score 2):

This sample sub, which uses a provider-specific schema, will list users. You need to pass a valid connection, for example:

```
ADOUserList Currentproject.Connection

  Public Sub ADOUserList(oConn As ADODB.Connection)
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
      Set rs = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , _
          "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")
      Debug.Print rs.GetString
      rs.Close
  End Sub
```

The fields returned are:

```
COMPUTER_NAME
LOGIN_NAME
CONNECTED
SUSPECT_STATE
```

Comment: In my experience, using `CurrentProject.Connection` is the only way to get the user list without locking the database. This technique still has the shortcoming that typically Access opens with the `LOGIN_NAME` admin. I've always had to match the `COMPUTER_NAME` to a login table to get the Windows username - it's a shortcoming of Access.